# php script is displaying a weired results

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am validating a form data using this script below.
When i submit the form if there is any errors the error message is displaying properly but if no errors and validation succeed i try to echo out the variables to test the script but the script is only displaying this : [] 
Please examine the code and help me solve this.

```
    <?php

//included files
include("./includes/connect.php");
include("./includes/functions.php");
$errors = array();

//checking if user have submitted the form
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    //validating and cleaning submitted form data ... 
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,20}$/", strip_trim($_POST['name']))) {
            $cln_name = clean_data($_POST['name']);
        } else {
            $_POST['name'] = FALSE;
            $errors[] = "The name you entered is not valid";
        }

    } else {
        $errors[] = "You have not enter your name!";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $cln_email = filter_var($_POST['email'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(filter_var($cln_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $cln_email = clean_data($cln_email);
        } else {
            $_POST['email'] = FALSE;
            $errors[] = "The email you entered is not valid";
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "You have not provide you email!";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['plate_num']) && !empty($_POST['plate_num'])) {
        if(ctype_alnum($_POST['plate_num']) && strlen($_POST['plate_num']) >= 5) {
            $cln_plate_num = clean_data($_POST['plate_num']);
        } else {
            $_POST['plate_num'] = FALSE;
            $errors[] = "The plate number you provided is not a valid plate number";
        }
    } else {
        $errors[]= "You have not provide a plate number";
    }
    //checking for errors and printing errors.. 
    if (count($errors > 0)) {

        $errors_to_json = json_encode($errors);
        echo $errors_to_json;
        //foreach ($errors as $error) {
            //echo $error . "<br />";
        //}
    } else {
        echo $cln_name . "<br />";
        echo $cln_email . "<br />";
        echo $cln_plate_num;
    }
} else {
    echo "You did not submit the form!";
}

?>
```

This script is returning only this :
[]

Any idea please ??

---

functions.php :

```
 <?php

function clean_data($data) {
    if(function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string')) {
        global $dbc;
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($data), $dbc);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
    } else {
        $data = mysql_escape_string(trim($data));
        $data = strip_tags($data);
    }
    return $data;
}


function strip_trim($data) {
    $data = stripslashes(trim($data));
    return $data;
}



?>
```

Comment: which file did the function `clean_data()` is defined? can you show me the contents of it? I assume it is in`./includes/functions.php` right?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: What is this? Why are you using this?  global $dbc;

Comment: $dbc is my database connection

Comment: Are using MySQLI or MySQL? Review your code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have problem in your if condition:

```
//checking for errors and printing errors.. 
if (count($errors > 0)) {
...
```

this will always return to `TRUE` because `$error = []` and `count([] > 0)` results to `TRUE`

that's why you always end up in:

```
$errors_to_json = json_encode($errors);
echo $errors_to_json;
// Will indeed display '[]' because json_encode([]) is '[]'
```

i believe what you mean here is:

```
if (count($errors) > 0) {
...
```